# SharePoint Online add-in publishing lists but all columns are missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app

Not sure where to go on this one and can't find anything online. I'm publishing my SharePoint 2013 Online add-in and the lists are appearing in the add-in. However every single list only has the Title column, and the library has the default Name/Modified/Modified By columns.

I'm using a content type for my library which I have marked as the default content type. The other lists have columns added to those manually. However both my Library and Lists will only show the Title field, I have checked the views in visual studio and they are correct, the view manager in the deployed list doesn't show the columns at all.

The schema.xml for each list contains the correct columns.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!